# HTTPS protocol omits the password parameter?

Tags: java, security, http, ssl, https

I'm calling one of our http services, it can be either called via http or https protocols. 
The code which generates the request is the same. It's a HttpClient, it passes parameters

```
final MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity();
    for (FormBodyPart bodyPart : requestParameters(username, password, format, version)) {
        reqEntity.addPart(bodyPart);
    }
    final HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(getUrl());
    httpPost.setEntity(reqEntity);

    final HttpResponse response = getHttpClient().execute(httpPost);
```

Now, the real weird problem is: when getUrl() returns http version of the service url - all works good. However, if I replace in properties the url protocol by https, - it starts omitting parameters. For example it definitely omits password parameter. I see it in the logs of the service I call - when I use https url - the password parameter is empty, as if it never been passed. 
Why something like that can happen? anyone seen it ever before?

Can it be because of ssl on the calling side encrypts password differently than ssl on the service side decrypts it? Where can I read more about it?

Comment: When you say the "password" parameter, you're not talking about something like `http://username:password@example.com/...`, right? That's been strongly deprecated for years...

Comment: @T.J.Crowder no, it's in my code: requestParameters(username, password, format, version)) {
        reqEntity.addPart(bodyPart);

Comment: @T.J.Crowder so it is just one of the typical POST http parameters

Comment: Okay, good. I think you'll need to do a more complete [MCVE](/help/mcve), as there's no reason the protocol should affect your POST parameters.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I'm not saying it must be a protocol, maybe something else in between the one pplication making this https call and another one receiving request. Can it be apache? Any other idea..